# MarkerWithLabel not showing full custom icon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

We are using google utility script to have a custom icon with information below it.

```
var marker5 = new MarkerWithLabel({position: point, 
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    raiseOnDrag: false, 
    labelContent: infor,
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 0),
    labelClass: "labels",         // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
    icon: {
      url: entImage,
      size: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(20, 0)
    },
    marker: MarkerWithLabel
});
```

The issue when we size the icon using  new google.maps.Size(30, 30) it could not show up the full icon just partial of it. How ensure that when we resize it covers the whole image.

Comment: What is the icon you are using?  How big is it? Did you try using [scaledSize](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [specify size of custom marker in google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457527/specify-size-of-custom-marker-in-google-map/19457833#19457833)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem via a simple way and for the benefit of the rest just create one image icon like this

```
var pIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('logo.png',
                                  null,
                  null,
                  null,
                  new google.maps.Size(30, 30));
```

Thereafter just apply into the rest of the codes.